# Applescript : Javascript to click in safari with unknown id

Tags: javascript, applescript

How can I click in the "detailed" button listed bellow ?

```
<span data-segment-id="bererf44b-be45-4514-922a-0fff0585gb">
    <input type="radio" id="dccd7242-38d2-4f54-4841-73c4b48a2f56-view-selector-bererf44b-be45-4514-922a-0fff0585gb" name="dccd7242-38d2-4f54-4841-73c4b48a2f56-view-selector" value="detailed">
    <label for="dccd7242-38d2-4f54-4841-73c4b48a2f56-view-selector-bererf44b-be45-4514-922a-0fff0585gb">Detailed</label>
</span>
```

This work but I have to enter manually the encrypted id

```
tell application "Safari Technology Preview" to ¬
    do JavaScript ¬
        "document.querySelectorAll(\"[for=\\\"dccd7242-38d2-4f54-4841-73c4b48a2f56-view-selector-bererf44b-be45-4514-922a-0fff0585gb\\\"]\")[0].click();" in current tab of window 1
```

UPDATE :

Most of the HTML is dynamic, and I can't very relie on it.

```
<div class="center">
            <div class="segmented-control view-selector component" id="THIS_IS_DYNAMIC">
    <input type="radio" id="THIS_IS_DYNAMIC" name="THIS_IS_DYNAMIC" value="basic">
    <label for="THIS_IS_DYNAMIC">Basic</label>
</span><span data-segment-id="THIS_IS_DYNAMIC">
    <input type="radio" id="THIS_IS_DYNAMIC" name="THIS_IS_DYNAMIC" value="detailed">
    <label for="THIS_IS_DYNAMIC">Detailed</label>
</span></div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your post you want to trigger a click on the `<label` element.
Your main problem is that you have to manuelly enter the encrypted id.

I suggest you search for the `<label`element with the value `'Detailed'`.

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('label')].find(x=>x.innerText=='Detailed' || x.textContent == 'Detailed').click(); //triggers onclick

// or use

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('label')).find(x=>x.innerText=='Detailed' || x.textContent == 'Detailed').click()


// hint. document.querySelectorAll doesn't return a normal array but a nodelist
```

Edit: Changed `<input` element to `<label` element.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I don't work in my side but surly it's something I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I've updated my answer (added some description). @Kevin It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I'm sorry my question wasn't clear at the start, but unfortunately I can't use the label neither (dynamic too) but I found a work around with `<div class="segmented-control view-selector component"`

```
tell application "Safari Technology Preview" to ¬
    do JavaScript ¬
        "document.querySelectorAll(\"[value=\\\"detailed\\\"]\")[0].click();" in current tab of window 1
```